# How to scroll with animation

Tags: android, scrollview, android-animation

I am trying to create an app for which i need to scroll down programmatically upon receiving some message..

I have tried using `ScrollView` using following code

```
ScrollView mScrollView;
mScrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.abc);

mScrollView.post(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 
                     mScrollView.scrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());

                } 
        });
```

It works and it takes me to bottom , but there's no animation like actual scrolling.
How can i get "scrolling animation" along with that?

is there any other way to scroll programmatically with animation? please help me out.

Comment: tried smoothScrollTo?

Comment: there are a couple of links too:-
https://github.com/blessenm/AndroidAutoScrollListView

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854113/android-how-to-add-vertical-auto-scroll-feature-to-scrollview-or-textview

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343

Comment: it worked ... thanks ... i didn't noticed that method ... silly me

Comment: If it is solved, post the solution as an answer and accept it. Adding "[Solved]" to the title is not how it works here.

Comment: @Gerald i got answer as a comment , so how can i accept it ?? i have already up voted that & added how i fixed it on the beginning of my post in BOLD.

Comment: Usually you ask the person to post their solution as an answer. If the user doesn't react you can post it yourself and mark it as "community wiki". By doing that you show that the solution isn't yours and you aren't taking credit for it.

Comment: @pskink please post your solution as answer so i can accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using ScrollView.smoothScrollTo method