# HorizontalScrollView which auto scrolls automatically in every 2min time interval

Tags: android

I had used HorizontalScrollView and i want this horizantalscrollview scroll automatically in every time interval from right to left.
And when it comes to end of horizontalscrollview then it again scroll from the beginning.
I had used the code like:

```
    mHorizontalScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mHorizontalScrollView, "scrollX", 500);
            animator.setDuration(1000);
            animator.start();
        }
    },100);
```

But it scroll only one time when application start.

And i had go throw this link:
https://github.com/blessenm/AndroidAutoScrollListView
but it is scroll HorizantalScrollView contineous but i want an time delay.

Thank's in advance

Comment: Use a `CountDownTimer` instead

Comment: May this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854113/android-how-to-add-vertical-auto-scroll-feature-to-scrollview-or-textview

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will only performed once. This is because you only posted the Runnable once. Simply call   `mHorizontalScrollView.postDelayed(myRunnable,100)` in the run method. Therefore you should not define the Runnable inline.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry i did not  get it, can you explain it little more.

Comment: No problem, mHorizontalScrollView.postDelayed(myRunnable,100) will post the runnable once and it will be performed after 100 ms (run method is called). If you want that the Runnable is called continuously you should again call mHorizontalScrollView.postDelayed(myRunnable,100) in the run method.